# What's difference between upper and lower case 'b' when addressing problems about memory in computer system?

Tags: cpu-architecture

For example, what is the meaning of 64B in
"64KB 8-way, 64B block, Virtually Indexed, Physically Tagged, write-allocate, write-back I$ and D$."
My instructor said that it is different from 64bit but I couldn't find an answer on the internet.

Comment: "block" is being used as a synonym for cache line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, and in SI units: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte:

- upper-case `B` means byte (usually 8 bits)
- lower-case `b` means bit.

64-byte line size is totally normal for L1 caches on a modern CPU, and it's normal to specify cache sizes in bytes.

BTW, I$ won't be write-back; instruction caches are read-only in any normal architecture.